# Formatting the schedule on last day of quarter for Google Cloud Function (Firebase function scheduled using Google Pub/Sub) - Node.js 8

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I wish to schedule Google Cloud Function execution one time each quarter. On the last day of March, June, September and December, it should run at 23:00.

I've found `cron.yaml` syntax for first day of quarter to run at 00:00 as following:

```
1 of jan,april,july,oct 00:00
```

[cron.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref?authuser=1#formatting_the_schedule)

For my requirements, two months are ending at 30th and other two at 31st. So I can't use given reference syntax as it considers same date for each following month.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, I believe you will need to use cron expressions to achieve that. Using cron expressions you will have more options and alternatives to set a date to run the function on the last day of months.

For example, if you use the cron expression below:

```
0 0 23 L 1,4,7,10 ?
```

It will run on the last day of January, April, July, and October - covering the months from the end of the quarters. This way, you would replace that format for this one.

This article [here](https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-using-the-cloud-scheduler-to-trigger-your-functions-756160a95c43), provides a full tutorial to trigger functions with cloud scheduler and cron expressions.

More information on Cron Expressions and how to create them can be found on this other article [here](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions).

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Article on Cron Expressions covers most of the syntax for cron schedule. But the required `L` (last) field is not supported by Google Cloud Scheduler. I've found another article for Google Cloud Scheduler to schedule cron using unix-cron format [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules?authuser=1#defining_the_job_schedule).

Comment: Nice! Thanks for providing this link @AppTechie